# Data annotation, dataframe merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to annotate data (a liste of names in a column) with the content of a column of a second dataframe (containing some atributes of these names).
Like dataframe 1 :

```
id      name             col
----------------------------
 29834   Marie Peer
890384   Marie Peach
 30047   Susan Peer
```

with an other dataframe containing

```
name       city
---------------------
Marie      Chicago
Marie      Boston 
Harley     Milan 
Josh       London
```

**Questions**:

- Shall I better use pandas or does it worth to create python dictionaries?
- I previously used `data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='column_name', how='left')` but how does it work if my second dataframe has multiple times the same row in the column (I would need them to go in the same row of a new column of the first dataframe).

  I would need that, if 'Marie' has multiple entries in the second dataframe, that annotate in a new column the multiple entries of 'Marie' from the second df
  output needed :

  ```
   29834 Marie Peer      Chicago, Boston
  890384 Marie Peach     Chicago, Boston
   30047 Susan Peer
  ```

  (and if there is no entry in the second dataframe, like for 'Susan' here, the field would stay blank)
- In general is that the best way to annotate a dataset with data from an other dataset ?

Many thanks in advance (and apologies, i'm a beginner though that might sound very basic questions) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join` for second DataFrame, so possible use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2.groupby('name')['city'].apply(', '.join), on='name')
print (df)
       id   name    col             city
0   29834  Marie   Peer  Chicago, Boston
1  890384  Marie  Peach  Chicago, Boston
2   30047  Susan   Peer              NaN
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['city'] = df1['name'].map(df2.groupby('name')['city'].apply(', '.join))
print (df1)
       id   name    col             city
0   29834  Marie   Peer  Chicago, Boston
1  890384  Marie  Peach  Chicago, Boston
2   30047  Susan   Peer              NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.groupby('name')['city'].apply(', '.join))
name
Harley              Milan
Josh               London
Marie     Chicago, Boston
Name: city, dtype: object
```